# Proof of winograd convolution

Tags: algorithms, convolution, neural-networks

I am trying to prove equation (7) in [Fast Algorithms for Convolutional Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.09308.pdf#page=2)

Could anyone elaborate on the mathematical relationship between [Vandermonte Matrix](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Numerical_Analysis/Vandermonde_example) and [winograd convolution](https://github.com/NervanaSystems/neon/issues/224#issuecomment-529021396) ?

Comment: Look in Winograd's book "Arithmetic complexity of computations", page 42, and then go back to the beginning of chapter IV for some context.

Comment: You can see that he uses Langrange interpolation in some way. Do you already know the relation between Lagrange interpolation and the Vandermonde matrix?

Comment: At page 42, Winograd uses a special root called infinity (in addition to 0, 1, -1), and it seems that it corresponds to the last column [0; 0; ...; 1] of the matrix called AT at the GitHub page. You can imagine that this column vector is parallel to the vector [1; infinity; ...; infinity^n] by a scaling factor of infinity^(n-1). So AT is a (somewhat nonstandard due to infinity) Vandermonde matrix up to a scaling of the columns.

Comment: @JoelSjögren I am not aware of the relation between Lagrange interpolation and the Vandermonde matrix

Comment: @JoelSjögren I also saw the use of root of infinity in the book. However, I do not understand why is it done that way ?

Comment: It is very easy (or computationally efficient) to evaluate a polynomial p = a + bx + ... + sx^n at 0 since the result is just p(0) = a. That's why the the root 0 is used, it seems. Similarly it is easy to evaluate at 1 and -1 because you only have to add and subtract things. And similarly it is easy to evaluate at infinity because the result is s*infinity^n (plus lower order terms) which is basically just the last coefficient s.

Comment: @JoelSjögren However, the root of inifinity is used in modulo operations ? Besides, how is Lagrange interpolation related to Vandermonde matrix ?

Comment: I do not quite understand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Constructing_the_interpolation_polynomial

Comment: @JoelSjögren See equation (28) of https://github.com/andravin/wincnn/blob/master/2464-supp.pdf to understand why root of infinity is used.

Comment: @JoelSjögren I do not understand why the proposed [toom-cook ALGORITHM 1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.10986.pdf#page=7) in the paper _Error Analysis and Improving the Accuracy of Winograd Convolution for Deep Neural Networks_ does not need [polynomial interpolation stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication#Interpolation) ?

Comment: The algorithm does use polynomial interpolation: The inverse of the Vandermonde matrix provides efficient polynomial interpolation (lagrange interpolation) as matrix multiplication. It stores all coefficients of the lagrange basis polynomials for the chosen interpolation points. The algorithm computes Mij and Ni which are numerator and 1/denominator of those coefficients.

Comment: @JoelSjögren Why Vandermonde matrices tend to be numerically unstable for large sizes ?

Comment: and in [On improving the numerical stability of winograd convolutions](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=H1ZaRZVKg#page=2) , why SY·SX·SW=I ?

Comment: About stability I don't know. The requirement SY·SX·SW=I makes (2) reduce, after expansion in terms of them, into an expression not involving them.

Comment: @JoelSjögren Wait, why would that requirement help to reduce equation (2) ?

Comment: I'll denote the pointwise product by (.*). Using the general identities diag(u)*(A.*B) = (diag(u)*A).*B = A.*(diag(u)*B) and diag(u.*v) = diag(u)*diag(v) you can extract SY*SX*SW on both sides.

Comment: @JoelSjögren what is **diag(u)** ?

Comment: I mean like in matlab, the diagonal matrix with elements from the vector u.

Comment: @JoelSjögren and what is the difference between .* and * ?

Comment: * is ordinary matrix multiplication, .* is pointwise matrix multiplication.

Comment: @JoelSjögren What do you exactly mean by **extract SYSXSW on both sides** ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105551/discussion-between-joel-sjogren-and-kevin).

Answer (score 1):

Here are the transcribed equations from [Fast Algorithms for Convolutional Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.09308.pdf#page=2).

$F(2, 3)=\begin{bmatrix}
d_0 & d_1 & d_2\\ 
d_1 & d_2 & d_3
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
g_0\\
g_1\\
g_2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
m_1+m_2+m_3\\
m_2-m_3-m_4
\end{bmatrix}$

where

$\begin{align}
m_1&=(d_0-d_2)g_0\\
m_2&=(d_1+d_2)\frac{g_0+g_1+g_2}{2}\\
m_3&=(d_2-d_1)\frac{g_0-g_1+g_2}{2}\\
m_4&=(d_1-d_3)g_2
\end{align}$

As this should be easy to derive out as true, I would continue with explaining equation (7).

$\begin{align}
B^T&=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&-1&0\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&-1&1&0\\
0&1&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}\\
G&=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}\\
A^T&=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&0\\
0&1&-1&-1
\end{bmatrix}\\
g&=\begin{bmatrix}
g_0&g_1&g_2
\end{bmatrix}^T\\
d&=\begin{bmatrix}
d_0&d_1&d_2&d_3
\end{bmatrix}^T
\end{align}$

So, plugging these in into equation (6), we get:

$Y=A^T[(Gg)⊙(B^Td)]\\
=A^T\left[\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
g_0\\
g_1\\
g_2
\end{bmatrix}\right)⊙\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&-1&0\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&-1&1&0\\
0&1&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
d_0\\
d_1\\
d_2\\
d_3
\end{bmatrix}\right)\right]\\
=A^T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
g_0\\
\frac{g_0+g_1+g_2}{2}\\
\frac{g_0-g_1+g_2}{2}\\
g_2
\end{bmatrix}⊙\begin{bmatrix}
d_0-d_2\\
d_1+d_2\\
d_2-d_1\\
d_1-d_3
\end{bmatrix}\right)\\
=A^T\begin{bmatrix}
m_1\\
m_2\\
m_3\\
m_4
\end{bmatrix}\\
=\begin{bmatrix}
m_1+m_2+m_3\\
m_2-m_3-m_4
\end{bmatrix}$

As for the mathematical relationship between Vandermonde matrix and Winograd convolution, no idea. However, I did spot equation (15), which looks like a Vandermonde matrix.

$A^T=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1&0\\
0&1&-1&2&-2&0\\
0&1&1&4&4&0\\
0&1&-1&8&-8&1
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: What is the significance of equation (15) with respect to the proof ? and how is that looking like a Vandermonde matrix ?

Comment: Consider each column of the matrix, they are the powers of 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, with exception of the last column.

Comment: powers of 0, 1, -1, 2, -2  ?  you have only 5 numbers here, but we have a matrix of the size 4x6 ?

Comment: ...and it seems the last column is a rescaled powers of infinity

Comment: What do you exactly mean by **rescaled powers of infinity** ?

Comment: Refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3347049/proof-of-winograd-convolution/3347089?noredirect=1#comment6889671_3347049

Comment: How do we even obtain equation (6) in the first place ?

Comment: Why [The down-side of Cook-Toom algorithms is that the transforms quickly become unstable as the transform size increases](https://github.com/andravin/wincnn/blob/master/FAQ.md) ?

Comment: Looks like a really different question from here, try asking?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3356292/disadvantage-of-cook-toom-algorithm

By the way, for https://github.com/andravin/wincnn/blob/master/2464-supp.pdf ， How to derive equations 28，29 and 30 ？

Comment: Why [Fast Algorithms for Convolutional Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.09308.pdf#page=2) does not make use of [modulo polynomial used in andravin wincnn github](https://github.com/andravin/wincnn/blob/master/2464-supp.pdf) ?

Comment: How to derive the filter transformation matrix G ?

Comment: The gist of winograd transformation matrix could be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication#Interpolation